# How to swap values for a categorical variables?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 5 variables and 802 observations. One of my categorical variables called fruits can have either of 4 possible values apple, orange, banana and grapes. Using R How do I change all my observations containing value orange with value apple, keeping rest of the data frame intact?

Comment: Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will replace all observations with orange to apple.  You will have to update the code below to match whatever your data frame and actual column name is. In the code below I am calling the column `fruit_column` and the data frame `data`.  Keep in mind R is case sensitive.  If there are instances with upper and lower case spellings of the fruit, set the `ignore.cases` argument to "FALSE" in the gsub function below.

```
data$fruit_column <- gsub("orange", "apple", data$fruit_column)
```

Comment: Well it is not substituting the values in my original data frame and rather storing the new values in my global environment (I am not sure as a new variable after swapping the values), which I cannot use with other variables in my original data frame for further operation.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you need here.  If you want to assign those same values to a new variable rather than replace them in the current data frame, use the code in my answer but replace "data$fruit_column" with a new variable name.  new_variable <- gsub("orange", "apple", data$fruit_column)